# C#. DLLImport. Ошибка DLLNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dllimport

Проблема в следующем:

1. Взял исходный код эмулятора IP камеры (https://github.com/inspiredtechnologies/IP-Camera-Emulator)
2. Собрал решение, один из проектов (та самая dll) на C++

После успешной сборки получил приложение и c++'ную dll.
Запускаю приложение, добавляю видео-файл и нажимаю Start - получаю ошибку DLLNotFoundException, хотя эта DLL лежит рядом с exe файлом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приложении импорт делает так:

```
[DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRtspStreamerLib();

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void DestroyRtspStreamerLib(IntPtr lib);

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern Int32 StartStreamLib(IntPtr lib, byte[] streamName, byte[] mediaPath, Int32 portNumber);

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void StopStreamLib(IntPtr lib);

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool GetStreamStatusLib(IntPtr lib);

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern Int32 GetStreamRateLib(IntPtr lib);

    [DllImport("RtspStreamerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetVlcVersionLib(IntPtr lib);
```

Собственно, как решить проблему?
Через ProcMon посмотрел, приложение пытается загрузить DLL, путь до файла верный, но некоторые обращения отображаются с результатом FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускали regsvr32?

Comment: @AK, да, но DLL не регистрируется, "Не удалось загрузить модуль <ИМЯ DLL>. Не найден указанный модуль"

Comment: @AK, я так понимаю у этой DLL есть какие-то зависимости, которых не хватает...

Comment: Не регистрируется? Вы как регистрировали? Просто без ключей `regsvr32 имя_dllки`?

Comment: @AK, я разобрался, нужны были еще рядом DLL от VLC с плагинами...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что требовались еще Vlc.dll и VlcCore.dll + папка plugins от VLC...